# Mongoid Relational Queries Syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I'm having issues using a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship. I have the following:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_and_belongs_to_many :subjects
end

class Subject
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, :type => String
  attr_accessible :name
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

Then in my controller I am trying to find all users that have a particular subject:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @users = User.where('subjects.name' => 'Physics')
    end
end
```

Am I going about this the right way?

Comment: is your name of subject is primary_key?

Answer (score 1):

```
def index
    @subjects = Subject.where('name' => 'Physics')
    @subjects.each do |subject|
     @users = subject.users
    end
end
```

This gives the users per subject.

Comment: `@subjects = Subject.where('name' => 'Physics')` to `@subjects = Subject.where(:name => 'Physics')` (this is just a syntax thing, i think its more 'rails way' like this), or better `@subjects = Subject.find_by_name('Physics')`

Comment: Does this give me all the users that match the subject as one object though?

Answer (score 1):

There is probably only one `subject` named `Physics`.
I think the code should be something like:

```
@subject = Subject.find_by_name('Physics')
@users = @subject.users
```

This should be a nested route and probably not in the index page of the UsersController.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

EDIT:
Or actually if not a nested route, you should put that code in the SubjectsController like this:

```
def index
    @subject = Subject.find(params[:id])
    @users = @subject.users
end
```

or if you pass the name as the parameter:

```
def index
    @subject = Subject.find_by_name(params[:name])
    @users = @subject.users
end
```

EDIT2:
Based on what Harrison James told me in the comments:

```
Subject.find(:all, :conditions => ["name LIKE ?", "%#{params[:name]}%"])
```

Comment: I suppose that the name attribute has a unique constraint, so it would act as a 'primary key' in that sense. I have edited my answer..

Comment: Although i might be wrong since he doesn't validate the uniqueness in the Subject model, but who knows..

Comment: Name is unique, and though Zippie is correct in saying that there is only one subject called 'Physics', I did want to leave this open to matching more than one subject in the future. For example, there are a few subjects that contain the string "Math", so a query to "Math" should match all of them.

Comment: oh, then you should use regex to match that

Comment: Okay, i have updated the answer, tell me if that works for you